# device boots into recovery every time I reboot, probably because playing with a system app

Tags: samsung, recovery-mode, boot, titanium-backup

Today I removed chrome browser that was a system app. At first unintentionally my hand tapped on "integrate updated system app into rom" (titanium backup app) and my immediate attempts to cancel it failed, and chrome icon changed to android robot. Then without any restart I uninstalled it using titanium backup, so that icon got disappeared.

I used my phone for a couple of hours until I attached it to the charger and turned it off. Now every time I reboot, it boots into recovery (twrp 3.0.2).

My phone is Sm-J510F with official android 7.1.1 and it's rooted.

Is there any hope I can boot into system without factory reset?

Answer (score 0):

There can be several possibilities so let's check step by step

1. check whether your volume kye is not pressed ( what happens if your device has fallen down by the volume side there are chances that the volume button would have got pressed.

2.if the 1st is not your problem then try checking your Rom setting if your device is rooted. there are chances that while flashing custom rom your rom would have been not flashed properly so the device gets into a loop and is not able to load your rom.

3. if not rooted, then there are chances that the problem is with your rom.

**solution**
Try hard resetting your device this may fix it.
or reinstalling your device rom.
some time while restoring the device can also cause this problem. so I would suggest checking your rom once. if still, the problem persists comment down will try some other fix.
*wish you luck..*

Comment: 1. not pressed, 2. rom is flashed properly and I was using it for months ( > 6 month ), 3. it's rooted, 4. I'm looking for a way other than reseting it. It would be my last chance.